# Remove old iMac from network?

Tags: network, file-sharing

Every time I boot up my iMac this message appears: 'cannot connect to [the name of my old iMac] server.' The old iMac was finally laid to rest several months ago. How can I remove it from the network preferences in my iMac?

I'm using MacOSX 10.12.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll hazard a guess that the connection to your old iMac is one you set up on your new iMac. Here are some places to look, if this isn't it, please let us know:

- Look in `Control Panel`, the `Users & Groups` item, the tab labeled `Login items`. Is there a reference in there to a folder or anything to do with the old iMac?
- In `Control Panel`, the `Sharing` item. Open this, and look for anything shared with your old iMac.

Hopefully, it will be one of these, but if not, perhaps edit your question to provide a bit more information. It's difficult to say *what* information exactly, but an example would be if you used the old iMac as a network connection, used VNC to connect to it, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I found a couple of items in the login items that were marked 'unknown' and deleting them has apparently solved the error. :)